# Are we allowed to dye our hair?

Tags: halal-haram, hair, dyeing-hair

Are we allowed to dye our hair in Islam?

These two hadiths contradict each other

> Dawud :: Book 34 : Hadith 4210
>
> Narrated Abdullah ibn Mas'ud:
>
> The Prophet of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) **disliked ten things**: Yellow colouring, meaning khaluq, **dyeing grey hair**, trailing the lower garment, wearing a gold signet-ring, a woman decking herself before people who are not within the prohibited degrees, throwing dice, using spells except with the Mu'awwidhatan, wearing amulets, withdrawing the penis before the semen is discharged, in the case of a woman who is wife or not a wife, and having intercourse with a woman who is suckling a child; but he did not declare them to be prohibited.

**This one says prophet did not like dyeing hair.**

> Bukhari :: Book 7 :: Volume 72 :: Hadith 786
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira :
>
> The Prophet said, "Jews and Christians do not dye their hair so you should do the opposite of what they do.

**This one tells us to dye our hair**.

Also if dyeing is possible then what colours are allowed?

Answer (score 2):

The first hadith says, The Prophet (Salla-Allahu-Alaihi-Wa-Sallam) disliked dying of gray hairs, dying gray hairs is usually used as a method to beautify one's self, the prophet may have been saying that he disliked it when men dyed their hair in order to hide it to look more attractive. There could be many reasons for this, maybe it was too feminine or maybe he liked the look of gray hairs, or that gray hairs are something one should show off. Whatever the case he disliked people hiding the gray hairs.

The second hadith said, to dye hair to distinguish our religion. This would be different than a method to make oneself more attractive, this is being done in order to give members of Islam distinction between other religions. So it may be that the prophet disliked it when people dyed their hair for beautification, but he encouraged one to dye their hair to distinguish themselves as a Muslim.

Also, gray hairs is already a color that is different from Jews and Christians, if ones hair is gray, then they are already distinguished from other religions and there is no need to dye there hair which may be another reason why the prophet disliked it.

Comment: as you said,"...gray hairs is already a color that is different from Jews and Christians....". Do you mean Jews and Christians do not have grey hair.? Seriously.!?

Answer (score 2):

> **but he did not declare them to be prohibited.**

I have heard that we shouldn't dye out hair black but nothing about any other colours.

Jaabir ibn ‘Abdullah reported that Abu Quhaafah was brought on the day of the conquest of Makkah, and his head and beard were white like "thaghaamah" (a plant whose flowers and fruit are white). The Messenger of Allah (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) said: "Change this with something, but avoid black." (Reported by Muslim, no. 3962).

Ibn ‘Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him) said: "The Messenger of Allah (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) said: ‘At the end of time there will be people who will dye their hair black like the crops of pigeons. They will never even smell the fragrance of Paradise." (reported by Imam Ahmad, see also Saheeh al-Jaami‘, no. 8153).

It was also reported from the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) that one should change grey hair, using any colour except black. Abu Dharr reported that the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allah be upon Him) said: "The best things with which to change grey hair are henna and ‘katam’ (a plant similar to henna which is used as a dye)." (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, no. 1675; he said: This is a saheeh hasan hadith).

Answer (score 1):

Dying hairs is allowed for warriors in warzone so that they can have more impact on the enemies.

There are grey areas, not everything is black and white. However dying them just coz you want to look more attractive isn't advisable imho. Join gym and work on other aspects of your personality to look better.

Comment: Why would joining gym to look more attractive be halal while dying hair (non-black) to look more attractive is not?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can dye your hair. In islamic school, my teacher had once said that you can dye your hair, as long as the products in it are halal, that you don't do it to hide age or to make your self more attractive. Also, it is preferable to dye it a colour that would be classed as "normal" in your town.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Please consider adding evidence to support your claim.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that The second Hadith which is in regards to dying with the aim of being different from Jews is about dying hair with henna as Jews do not use henna. And the first mentioned hadith is actually about dying with chemical treatments.

Comment: You can support you asnwer using authentic hadiths. Besides I'd like to ask: Did they really used to colour the hair using chemicals. Could the synthesis such chemicals.

Comment: Jews are allowed to use Henna (temporary) tattoos, please get your facts right